# What is the idiomatic way to write a packed binary file in Go that would produce the same output as this Python?

Tags: go, binaryfiles

I'm trying to figure out <del>how</del> the best way to write a binary file in Go that corresponds with the following Python:

```
import struct
f = open('tst.bin', 'wb')
fmt = 'iih'
f.write(struct.pack(fmt,4, 185765, 1020))
f.close()
```

I have been tinkering with some of the examples I've seen on Github.com and a few other sources <del>but I can't seem to get anything working correctly</del>.  **What is the idiomatic way to do this sort of thing in Go?**

Here is how I am accomplishing this now (Golang):

```
package main
import (
        "fmt"
        "os"
        "encoding/binary"
        )


func main() {
        fp, err := os.Create("tst.bin")

        if err != nil {
                panic(err)
        }

        defer fp.Close()

        aBuf := make([]byte, 4)
        bBuf := make([]byte, 4)
        cBuf := make([]byte, 2)

        binary.LittleEndian.PutUint32(aBuf, 4)
        binary.LittleEndian.PutUint32(bBuf, 185765)
        binary.LittleEndian.PutUint16(cBuf, 1020)

        binary.Write(fp, binary.LittleEndian, aBuf)
        binary.Write(fp, binary.LittleEndian, bBuf)
        binary.Write(fp, binary.LittleEndian, cBuf)
}
```

Verified with this Python:

```
import numpy as np

data = np.fromfile('tst.bin', dtype='i4,i4,i2')

print(data)
```

Comment: show people the result of your tinkering and where are you stuck

Comment: Salvador, I've mostly been working on the read end of this at the moment http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34078427/how-to-read-packed-binary-data-in-go I'll post my code once it is not embarrassing.

Comment: Working example posted but still would love feedback on a better, more idiomatic way of doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a little more tinkering and some feedback on another question I was able to come up with this (seems much cleaner but will post feedback on performance after testing with generating some large files):

```
package main
import (
        "os"
        "encoding/binary"
        )

type binData struct {
    A int32
    B int32
    C int16
}

func main() {
        fp, err := os.Create("tst.bin")

        if err != nil {
                panic(err)
        }

        defer fp.Close()
        bd := binData{A:4, B:185765, C:1020}

        binary.Write(fp, binary.LittleEndian, &bd)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in my question, I'm not sure this is THE idiomatic way to do this but after a fair bit of tinkering this does solve the problem I was having.  Posting so there is at least one answer in case someone else comes looking:

```
package main
import (
        "fmt"
        "os"
        "encoding/binary"
        )


func main() {
        fp, err := os.Create("tst.bin")

        if err != nil {
                panic(err)
        }

        defer fp.Close()

        aBuf := make([]byte, 4)
        bBuf := make([]byte, 4)
        cBuf := make([]byte, 2)

        binary.LittleEndian.PutUint32(aBuf, 4)
        binary.LittleEndian.PutUint32(bBuf, 185765)
        binary.LittleEndian.PutUint16(cBuf, 1020)

        binary.Write(fp, binary.LittleEndian, aBuf)
        binary.Write(fp, binary.LittleEndian, bBuf)
        binary.Write(fp, binary.LittleEndian, cBuf)
}
```

Slightly cleaning this up to make it more brief I'll be doing something like this:

```
func main() {
        fp, err := os.Create("tst.bin")

        if err != nil {
                panic(err)
        }

        defer fp.Close()

        lineBuf := make([]byte, 10) //sized large enough to hold my two 4 byte ints and one 2 byte int

        binary.LittleEndian.PutUint32(lineBuf[0:4], 4) //packing into 4 bytes
        binary.LittleEndian.PutUint32(lineBuf[4:8], 185765) 
        binary.LittleEndian.PutUint16(lineBuf[8:10], 1020) //packing into 2 bytes

        binary.Write(fp, binary.LittleEndian, lineBuf)
}
```